# Magento 2.3 override public function in Abstract Class

Tags: magento2.3, plugin, abstract-class

I need to override the `public function getValue(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $object)` in the `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbtsractFrontend`.
Can anyone tell me how to do it using a plugin (or a different way)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for that, a preference is enough you set it into the di.xml and then compile again

```
<preference for="Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Frontend\AbtsractFrontend" type="Project\Module\Model\....whateverlinkyouwant\YourCustomAbstractFrontend" />
```

You write your own class `YourCustomAbstractFrontend` which extends `AbtsractFrontend` and insode you can write your own method implementation for `getValue()`